# OpenSSL check if a SSL certificate is SHA-1 or SHA256 signed

Tags: certificates, openssl, digital-signature

How do I check if an OpenSSL certificate issued to a site is SHA-1 or SHA-256?

I have a quite a lot of intranet sites using OpenSSL certificates and I am a bit confused as when I check the certificate properties, I get:

- Internet Explorer:

  Signature Algorithm: sha1RSA
  Signature Hash Algorithm: sha1
- Firefox:

  Signature Algorithm: PKCS #1 SHA-1 With RSA Encryption
  Under Fingerprints, I see both SHA256 and SHA-1

#### OpenSSL command line attempt not working

I tried using OpenSSL command, but for some reasons it errors out for me and if I try to write to a file, the output file is created, but it is blank.

```
openssl.exe s_client -connect mysite:443 > CertInfo.txt && openssl x509 -text -in CertInfo.txt |
find "Signature Algorithm"
```

Basically, I need to validate that the certificates are really SHA-1 and I need to upgrade that to a SHA256 or SHA-2.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the answers to the following questions (although not exact duplicates): http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8645/how-do-i-check-if-a-gmail-gtalk-ssl-certificate-is-valid http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73824/steps-to-find-out-whether-a-ssl-certificate-is-trustworthy http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/59566/ssl-certificate-chain-verification

Comment: That certificate you tested with Firefox and IE is signed using SHA-1. And one more thing: fingerprints will not help you with your actual goal.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the command for Linux and Windows.

And don't be alarmed about the doubled output line (`Signature Algorithm:` ...). That is expected (and mandatory).

### Linux: SHA1 demo site

```
$ echo '' | openssl s_client -connect sha1.badssl.com:443 -servername sha1.badssl.com 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep 'Signature Algorithm'
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
```

### Linux: SHA256 demo site

```
$ echo '' | openssl s_client -connect sha256.badssl.com:443 -servername sha256.badssl.com 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep 'Signature Algorithm'
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
```

### Windows cmd.exe: SHA1 demo site

```
c:\>echo " " | openssl.exe s_client -connect sha1.badssl.com:443 -servername sha1.badssl.com 2>nul | openssl.exe x509 -noout -text | findstr /C:"Signature Algorithm"
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
```

### Windows cmd.exe: SHA256 demo site

```
c:\>echo " " | openssl.exe s_client -connect sha256.badssl.com:443 -servername sha256.badssl.com 2>nul | openssl.exe x509 -noout -text | findstr /C:"Signature Algorithm"
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
```

## Fingerprint is not inside certificate

It's a [computed value](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74389/should-the-thumbprint-be-sha2-in-addition-to-the-signature-hash-algorithm/74400).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to looking at `Signature Algorithm` (as mentioned in [the existing answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/106360/282580)), you may have to also look for `Hash Algorithm`.

For example, in case of `RSASSA-PSS` certificates, the signature algorithm just mentions `"rsassaPss"` but the hash algorithm indicates whether `SHA1` or `SHA256` is used.

```
$ openssl x509 -in sha1.pem -noout -text | grep -e 'Signature Algorithm' -e 'Hash Algorithm'
    Signature Algorithm: rsassaPss
     Hash Algorithm: sha1 (default)
Signature Algorithm: rsassaPss
     Hash Algorithm: sha1 (default)

$ openssl x509 -in sha256.pem -noout -text | grep -e 'Signature Algorithm' -e 'Hash Algorithm'
    Signature Algorithm: rsassaPss
     Hash Algorithm: sha256
Signature Algorithm: rsassaPss
     Hash Algorithm: sha256
```